# Java: readAllBytes reads metadata?

Tags: java, assertion

I'm comparing the content of two files as follows:

```
byte[] expectedContent = Files.readAllBytes(expectedPath);
byte[] generatedContent = Files.readAllBytes(generatedPath);
Assertions.assertTrue(Arrays.equals(expectedContent, generatedContent), "Content not equal)
```

IntelliJ show that both files are identical (also with regards to white-space, formatting etc)

[image]

Also comparing line by line works fine.

```
Scanner input1  = new Scanner(new File(expectedPath.toString()));
Scanner input2  = new Scanner(new File(generatedPath.toString()));
while(input1.hasNextLine() && input2.hasNextLine()){
    String first = input1.nextLine();
    String second = input2.nextLine();

    Assertions.assertTrue(first.equals(second), "Differences found: "+"\n"+first+'\n'+second);
}
```

However, comparing the byte arrays (`expectedContent` and `generatedContent`) fails. Why is that? Does `readAllBytes` read some metadata?

Comment: "comparing the byte arrays file" => what do you mean?

Comment: @assylias sry that was a typo.

Comment: I'd suggest using a tool that can show you a hash or checksum of each file... my guess is that they really are different, maybe just by line breaks (CRLF vs LF)

Comment: Your line-by-line comparison code has an obvious flaw: it fails to report if one file is a subset of the other. e.g. If one file has a single line and the other is blank, the while-loop will never execute.

Comment: Iterate over the array contents and print any index and bytes that are different (after making sure the lengths are equal).

Comment: Indeed @Jon Skeet, they just differ by single line break

Answer (score 0):

ReadAllBytes will do what it says, it will read all bytes in the file, including the byte order marker (BOM) of a unicode file.
You are almost certainly reading this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

To ensure the files are the same, look at them in a binary file editor and see if they are the same